# Javascript Iterate on Dynamic Object Created

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties

Here is my code. The problem is stated at the code lines

```
<script>


    // sample data created
    var names = ['egard', 'roger'];

    // object k is populated with a key and dynamic values
    // depending on the list of names

    // declare a new object
    var k = {};

    // create k properties according to names data
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

        if (k.hasOwnProperty(names[i])) {
            k[names[i]] = false;
        } else {
            // value is dynamic, can be a number, char
            // that will be used for other purposes
            Object.defineProperty(k, names[i], {
                value : true,
                writable : true
            });
        }
    };



    // using jquery
    $.each(k, function (i, me) {
        // its not going here
        console.log('jquery', me);
    });

    // using native iteration
    for (var i in k) {
        // its not going here
        console.log('native', k[i]);
    }

    // what i want is to go inside the block
    // of $.each or for ()
    // so that i could iterate the object
    // keys and its assign value

    console.log(k);
    // will output
    Object {egard: true, roger: true}


 console.log(k.egard);
    // will output
    // true
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your use of [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). By default it will create *non-enumerable* properties which, as the name suggests, cannot be enumerated by your loops. Just add the `enumerable` property to the definition:

```
Object.defineProperty(k, names[i], {
  value : true,
  writable : true,
  enumerable : true
});
```

Here's a [working version](https://jsfiddle.net/kwtaucmf/).

Answer (score 0):

you should be cautious about these two key values because they are `false`by default:

**configurable**
true if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.
Defaults to false.

**enumerable**
true if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object.
Defaults to false.